# jquery doesn't work in external file

Tags: jquery

I'm new to this so please be easy on me.
My style.css,js.js, and index are all in the same folder.
But jquery won't work for some reason and I don't understand why.
I tried putting it at the end of the body tag but still didn't work.
This is my HTML::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>Kurrac</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <button id="btt">press me gently</button>        
    </body>
</html>
```

My js.js file::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("btt").click(function(){
    alert("tell me if it works")}
)})
```

Comment: `#btt` .............

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Opening the browser's console would show you the errors you have.

Comment: @j08691 jquery compiler didn't check for `btt` is a valid selector or not. so, I guess there was no error in the console.

Comment: It seems you're pretty new to jquery, so let's make things simpler. Go back and learn some basics before posting simple questions please.

Comment: Perhaps you pressed the button *too* gently?

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect.

It should be:

```
$("#btt")
```

`btt` will look for a `<btt>` element.

`#btt` will look for an element with an `id` of `btt`.